# Is it possible to render html and send json to the angular scope in one response?

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, http, express

Simple example. Of course it doesn't work, but catch the idea please:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  Users.find ( {name: "John"}, function (err, users) {
      res.{ json: users, render: 'index' };
  });
});
```

Is it possible to send json data and render html in one response?

And in addition i want to send **users** to the angular $scope at the same time.

Is it possible?

Comment: Its a best practice not to mix data and template. The template should not be fetched more then once. The way i usually build angular apps is with a static server like github pages that is always up 24/7 and have a REST api with it on some server

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
res.render('your view',{
                foo : 'bar'
            });
```